# Spring Boot JPA Database Credentials

Tags: spring-boot

Is it possible (and if yes how) to let the user enter the database connection credentials either using a login form or a console prompt after the spring boot application was launched?

Comment: Personally I have not sont this. But what you could to do is to disable autoconfiguration of datasources and transaction manager and create this urself after the bootup(when u recieve password from user) and register it with spring

Comment: Do you know any example showing how to do that?

Comment: search for 
1. springboot configure datasource manually
2. register beans manually in spring

Answer (score 0):

You can also add them on your `SpringApplication` before running it. Create a map with your properties

```
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
properties.put("spring.application.name", "Test");
// properties.put("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto", "none");
properties.put("spring.datasource.url", url);
properties.put("spring.datasource.username", username);
properties.put("spring.datasource.password", password);
// properties.put("spring.liquibase.change-log", "classpath:/db/liquibase-changelog.xml");
```

and assign it to the application.

```
application.setDefaultProperties(properties);
application.run(args);
```